# OpenSSL version mismatch, but for only a specific user

Tags: curl, ssh, openssl, ssh-config

We upgraded our Linux server from SLES 12 to SLES 15.
Since then, one particular user on the server is not able to run ssh commands due to error:

```
  OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010009f, you have 10100060
```

userRED is not able to use ssh due to OpenSLL mismatch error.
userGREEN on the same server is able to ssh perfectly.

```
userRED@mySERVER:/home/appusers/userRED> ssh -vvv anotherSERVER 
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0f-dev  xx XXX xxxx
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1010009f, you have 10100060
userRED@mySERVER:/home/appusers/userRED>
userRED@mySERVER:/home/appusers/userRED> exit
mySERVER:~# exit
logout
userGREEN@mySERVER ~ (master) $ ssh -vvv anotherSERVER 
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0i-fips  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "sambaprod" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to anotherSERVER [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Check the env and PATH of the userRED which is having this OpenSSL error.
This user has curl and it's libraries in the path.
Even after removing the curl lib paths, ssh gives same error.

All other post about OpenSSL mismatch are server-wide and not for a specific user, where other users can use ssh perfectly.